# batch script to move x number of files to empty folders

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am new to batch scripts, and am looking for a script that can do the following:

I have a very large number of files, over 150000

these 150000 files are in dir/dir_main

I want to run a batch script, from windows cmd, such that it does the following

move 100 files at a time, doesn't matter which 100, to each subdirectory

dir/dir_main/subdir1

dir/dir_main/subdir2

dir/dir_main/subdir3

.

.

.

dir/dir_main/subdir#

notice the word **move** **not copy.**

I have found the following script, which moves all:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "source=C:\Users\msalehi\Documents\row-columnn fix\test_move\olddir"
SET "dest=C:\Users\msalehi\Documents\row-columnn fix\test_move\newdir"
SET "FileList=file1.txt file2.txt file8.txt" 

SET "dupCnt=1"

FOR /R "%source%" %%A IN (%FileList%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%%~NXA" (
        XCOPY /F /Y "%%~FA" "%dest%\" && IF EXIST "%%~FA" DEL /Q /F "%%~FA"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :DupeRoutine "%%~FA" "%%~NA" "%%~XA"
        )
    )
GOTO :EOF

:DupeRoutine
IF EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" (
    SET /A dupCnt=%dupCnt%+1
    CALL :DupeRoutine "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~1" "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" && DEL /Q /F "%~1"
    SET "dupCnt=1" 
    )
GOTO :EOF
```

not useful to me.

I am not looking to run this through other shell, linux, etc.

I need to run a batch file via windows cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
@echo off
set /a counter=1
set /a filesperfolder=100
cd dir\dir_main

:loopstart
set dirname=subdir%counter%
md %dirname%
echo %dirname%

dir /b | findstr /v /i "subdir*"> %temp%\temp.txt && for /l %%l in (1,1,%filesperfolder%) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r "^" %temp%\temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%%l:"') do @move %%b %dirname%\%%b >nul

set /a counter=%counter%+1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %temp%\temp.txt ^| find /c /v ""') do set _filesmoved=%%a
del %temp%\temp.txt
IF %_filesmoved% LSS 100 goto done

goto loopstart

:done
cls
echo All files were moved!!
pause
exit
```

The move command in the script moves all items in dir_main so folders as well (with the exception of newly created subdir folders) but this might not be a problem.
It will also take quite a while (powershell would probably be faster).
You should also run it in one go or up the counter variable (otherwise it will start again with creating subdir1)
It's not the best but I hope it's any use to you.

Comment: actually it works, just had to remove spaces in file names.

Comment: update: I tested only on 120 files yesterday, and it moves 100 and created subdir1. Today i tested on 200+, it gets stuck if i'm moving 200+ files. It doesn't go to create subdir2, subdir3.... , and it doesn't display the last echo msg .although the loop suggests it is to have that behavior. I'm not familiar with batch at all, but based on general code behaviour i think one of the variables is not being reseted for the next 100 to be grouped.

Comment: I just tested with 1000+ files and that does work.
I think that in your case script does not have access to the %temp%\temp.txt for some reason. This is where I list the files before moving them (kind of like an array but you don't have arrays or lists in batch). This file is also needed to display the end message. It could also be that the file is somehow deleted too early you could try to fix this by replacing the line "del %temp%\temp.txt" with "timeout 1 && del %temp%\temp.txt" without the quotes obviously.
I hope this helps to make  the script work for you!